# https is required for all redirect uris in login with facebook feature

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to use/allow http in Valid OAuth Redirect URIs?
For testing purposes.
I would like to test my app locally.

Maybe there's a way to disable the enforce HTTPS?